# /var/plone ownership

Tags: plone

could anyone help me on my problem, my /var/plone folder's ownership was accidentally changed. can anyone tell me who the owner of this folder? could it be www:root or www-data:root or root:root?

btw i changed it to www:root  and some images and styles cannot be loaded on my site.

Everytime somebody opens the site, it keeps loading and loading and after a few minutes it stops and some images are not loaded and style are not well displayed as it is supposed to be.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look in your /etc/passwd file to see if you have a "plone" or "zope" user id. If so, that's likely the owner your after. "plone" is the user id created by the Unified Installer if you're using sudo for the install.

Another place to check: your init script. It should be starting the zope daemon as the user that should own most of your plone directory.

Answer (score 0):

do a ps auxw and look at the user that runs plone. Then let him read and write. Next time you will run buildout, the permission should be fixed, at least that one in the parts directory.